# Access Map Data in LWC without using a for Each

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am quite new to Salesforce Apex and dev and there is something I do not get.
From what I understood Map are like dictionaries such as `{ 'Fiat': 'Punto', 'Toyota': 'Aygo }`

So I created a map of data in Apex, returned the data
and wired my data to my LWC and saved it within a variable let call it `param1`.

Now I would like to display my data in the LWC.
I can do a for each that loop through the data and display the key or the value

but I want to show only 1 piece of data. In python, I could do `param1['Fiat']` to get my data value

How can I do it in LWC?

thx you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your APEX Controller method returns some Map, for instance `Map<String, String>` in LWC the returned data structure will be presented as js object, but not as an instance of js Map class. For Instance:

```java
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static Map<String, String> getSomeMap(){
    return new Map<String, String>{ 'Fiat' => 'Punto', 'Toyota' => 'Aygo' };
}
```

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getSomeMap from '@salesforce/apex/Test.getSomeMap';

export default class Test extends LightningElement {
    map;

    @wire(getSomeMap)
    wiredContacts({ data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.map = data; // { Fiat: "Punto", Toyota: "Aygo" }
        }
    }
}
```

To access the object property you can either use

- [Dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):
  `data.Fiat // 'Punto'`
- [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):
  `data['Fiat'] // 'Punto'`

Please note that js is **case-sensitive** PL.

To display a specific value by key just use getter:

```js
key = 'Fiat';

get value() {
    return this.map?.[this.key];
}
```

You can use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) here to prevent TypeError [Cannot read property of undefined]

```html
<template>
    {value}
</template>
```

Every time when `key` reactive property changes the `value` on the markup rerenders.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
    import { getData} from '@salesforce/apex/classname.getData';
    
    export default class WireFunction extends LightningElement {
        @api recordId;
        @track showData = [];
    
        @wire(getData, { recordId: '$recordId'})
        wiredAccount({ error, data }) {
            if (data) {
           // you can place specific conditions if you need to and then use showData in html 
               this.showData.push(data['Fiat']);
            } 
        }
    
    }
```